# Deserializar json array en C#

Tags: c#, array, json, asp.net-core

Estoy intentando de muchas formas deserializar mi json en donde quiero extraer vehicle_id, registration y driver para almacenarlo en un modelo.

Como puedo hacer para obtener dichos datos sin considerar la primera partes del json: ejem. "1", "2", "3"....

Json ejemplo:

```
{
    "1": {
        "vehicle_id": "39504",
        "registration": "Y2P-964",
        "driver": "744"
    },
    "2": {
        "vehicle_id": "34640",
        "registration": "Y2G-968",
        "driver": "333"
    },
    "3": {
        "vehicle_id": "43293",
        "registration": "Y2H-961",
        "driver": "347"
    }
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo puedes deserializar a un Diccionario<string,TuModelo> y despues iterarlo para solo tener tu modelo en otra lista, como

```
List<TrackingData> list = new List<TrackingData>();
var deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, TrackingData>>(json);
foreach (var item in deserialized)
  list.Add(item.Value);
```

con su clase

```
    public class TrackingData
    {
        public string vehicle_id { get; set; }
        public string registration { get; set; }
        public string driver { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Gracias por el aporte, intenté de la forma que me indicas pero al momento deserializa no me almacena nada en el modelo, hay algo mas que me falte?

Comment: Añadí la etiqueta [JsonProperty("vehicle_id")] en mi modelo. Gracias por el apoyo